# Idioms similar to "crocodile tears"

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

What idiom would one use to show fake sympathy other than crocodile tears

Answer (score 1):

*While rubbing your thumb and index finger together* say:

> You: "You know what this is?"
>
> Victim: "No. What?"
>
> You: "It's the world's smallest violin playing just for you."

#### Explanation

Violin music is often the musical score accompanying sad scenes in movies when the audience is supposed to feel sadness or sorrow for the characters.

#### Example

[Here is an example in full context from the film Resevoir Dogs by Quintin Tarantino](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TPMEoM-cjc&t=1m55s).

(Link is already queued to proper time spot.)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TPMEoM-cjc&t=1m55s

Comment: But the listener would never mistake that for sympathy.